# An alternative to using the word "Resources"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

I am stuck with a labeling issue.

we have a software that allows users to publish content including release notes, product screencasts,white-papers etc. So far I have been using the label Resources to describe this content. An initial test revealed that the term is too generic. what would be the best choice of word to use to describe the different types of content that i mentioned.

I have tried using "Document library" and "Asset library" but still not convinced that it encompasses all the different types of content.

Any thoughts, ideas

Update to put this in context.The main issue is that I am catering for two populations viewing essentially the same thing but from different perspectives. For one population ( consumers) "Resources" does the job but for the other population ( makers) it doesn't

Comment: "An initial test revealed that the term is too generic". Have you considered that the **contents** of this folder are the cause of this? The three types of content you mentioned don't seem particularly related to one another.

Comment: Are those three the only contents you will be using?

Comment: types of content.

Comment: Have you tried searching synonyms for resources?

Comment: How about a **media library**?

Comment: @Michael totally understand your point. However if you consider the items as documents than all the different types within are kind of " standardised" they are all documents who happen to have different attributes. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You note in your keywords that you are looking for a single word replacement.  I see, though, that you are open to at least 2 words if it will do the job.

I believe "Resources & References" is what you are looking for.

The less wordy "Reference Materials" might work fine.

Rather than link to a dry grammatical reference, I am happy to use [this hilarious video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0HsX-M-zWQ) to support my suggestion.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using tools or materials (Resources:-alternates are tools,materials,stocks,assets,contents)

https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=resources+definition

Comment: Thanks for the link. Labelling is context sensitive hence the choice of word used needs to satisfy both language use and the context its being used in. I have updated my question to provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Try [Asset](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asset) (plural - assets)

> A resource, a valuable thing, an item of use or value owned.
>
> something useful in an effort to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned two word answers, I suggest combining what you think are the best two already given, such as: "Resource Tools", "Reference Tools", or "Reference Assets" as best suites your need.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the word "artifacts" used in this context, but that might wind up confusing both groups.

The usage I'm talking about comes from software development, and generally refers to the tangible by-products of the software development life cycle, as discussed at the Programmers Stack Exchange site under the question title "[What does 'artifact' mean?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/106473/what-does-artifact-mean)"

Comment: Please explain. :)

Comment: The usage I mean comes from software development, and generally means the tangible by-products of the software development life cycle as discussed here: [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/106473/what-does-artifact-mean]

Answer (score 0):

You say that "Resources" adequately describes the desired concept to consumers of the "Resources".

Perhaps if you call these things "Consumer Resources", consumers will understand this to mean the same thing as "Resources", but makers will understand this term to mean "something that I would regard as a Resource if I were a consumer."